# Change hidden field value on Submit click

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form with multiple items and an id attributed to each of these items, on Submit I want to be able to grab the id of the item that was clicked - I have tried using js, something like:

```
<form method="post" action="add_item_cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id">
    <input name="submit_item" id="btn_sub" onclick="document.getElementById('item_id').value = <?php echo '3'; ?>" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

I want to be able to grab this value: `$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];` on **add_item_cart.php**, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Is this a problem with my js syntax or is my logic not plausible to solve this problem? Is it submitting before changing the value?

EDIT:
Let's see if I can explain myself better, I want to assign that hidden value dynamically, imagine that my form has 3 submit buttons (one for each item displayed). Depending on the one that is clicked, I want to pass the item's id to my hidden field, so if I click button1 - $_POST["item_id"]=1, button2 - $_POST["item_id"]=2... etc

Here is my actual form (non simplified example)

```
<form method="post" action="add_item_cart.php">
                <table style="width:600px">
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
                            <td>
                        <center>
                            <span style="font-size:20px"><?php echo $item["item_name"] ?></span><br/>
                            €<?php echo $item["price"] ?><br/>
                            Quantidade: <input type="text" value="1" style="width:30px"><br/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id">
                            <input name="submit_item" id="btn_sub" onclick="document.getElementById('item_id').value = <?php echo $item["id"]; ?>" type="submit" value="Adicionar">
                        </center>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </form>
```

Comment: Is this a simplified example?  Any value that you are passing through PHP like `<?php echo "3"; ?>` could just as well be placed in the hidden input's value to begin with...

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add the value to the hidden input value on page load? -  `<input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id" value ="<?php echo '3'; ?>">`

Comment: Just a simplified example, I'm actually trying to echo an id that I grabbed from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your form is posted and you want to collect the item_id value on add_item_cart.php first you need to actually assign a value to id as in (Assuming item_id is a php variable). The id is just used for setting the css editing not a value...

```
<input type="hidden" id="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" name="item_id">
```

you cannot have id='' for the value because 'value' is value.

Then you can get that value on your other page with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['item_id'])){
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
}
?>
```

If you want to edit the variable after post depending on which button you hit you can try.

```
<input name="submit_item1" id="btn_sub" name="button1" type="submit" value="Add">
<input name="submit_item2" id="btn_sub" name="button1" type="submit" value="Add">
<input name="submit_item3" id="btn_sub" name="button1" type="submit" value="Add">
```

Then on the top of your page you can do.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_item1'])){
$item_id = 1;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit_item2'])){
$item_id = 2;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit_item3'])){
$item_id = 3;
}
?>
```

If you are creating forms from an array of items you could do something like, (assuming you somehow have an id associated with those items; I would need to know more information about how you are making your item list. But it would generally do like this.

```
<?php
foreach($item_array as $item){
?>
<form method="post" action="add_item_cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
    <input name="submit_item" id="btn_sub" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Then on the top of your page you can just get $_POST['item_id'] and since that value is dynamically set you do not need any conditionals you can just get that value and run any query.

Comment: Let's see if I can explain myself better, I want to assign that hidden value dynamically, imagine that my form has 3 submit buttons (one for each item displayed). Depending on the one that is clicked, I want to pass the item's id to my hidden field, so if I click button1 - $_POST["item_id"]=1, button2 - $_POST["item_id"]=2... etc

Comment: Oh if you are doing that then do no not even need a hidden field just figure out which button is pressed and then set the value... I will show an example above.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but I'd like this code to be as dynamic as possible, like being able to insert more items into the database and not having to keep adding button conditions...

Comment: Oh alright... I did not know this was for a list you were importing ok... I will make a dynamic example...

Comment: Early into this problem I considered multiple forms, it's a solution - just not the cleanest (in my opinion), but it seems like I'll have to go with this. Thanks for your help! right'd

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Use normal button instead of submit button and use javascript for submitting the form.

```
<form method="post" name="f1" action="add_item_cart.php">
<input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id">
<input name="submit_item" id="btn_sub" onclick="document.getElementById('item_id').value = <?php echo '3'; ?>; document.f1.submit();" type="button" value="Add">
```

Comment: Check my reply to Devon's answer, I will update the question as well.

Comment: No output from $_POST with this one either.